# How do I set flags in code in Stanford Information Extraction

Tags: stanford-nlp, information-extraction

Using Stanford information extraction we have the following java code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitymentions,depparse,natlog,openie");
props.put("tokenize.options", "latexQuotes=false");
props.put("openie","triple.extract=false,triple.all_nominals=false")
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

I want set some of the OpenIE flags (in props or something similar) available [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html).  So for example, the flag -triple.strict=false and -triple.all_nominals=true.  The approach I've taken is shown above and is

```
props.put("openie","triple.extract=false,triple.all_nominals=false")
```

It's not clear if this is correct or working.  Assuming these appear in props, how are they set there?  If not, how do I set them in code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost right. You should do:

```
props.put("openie.triple.extract", "false");
props.put("openie.triple.all_nominals", "false")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set those properties in a SeqClassifierFlags object in your code, then call the CRFClassifier's constructor with this object as you can see here:

```
public CRFClassifier(SeqClassifierFlags flags)
```

instead of calling

```
public CRFClassifier(Properties props)
```

from: https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier.html

Comment: In https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html it suggests "The code can also be invoked programatically, using Stanford CoreNLP. For this, simply include the annotators natlog and openie in the annotators property, and add any of the flags described above to the properties file prepended with the string "openie." And so I've added props.put("openie","triple.extract=false,triple.all_nominals=false"), but have no idea if that is right.